# A Problem about Only One Node in an Ignite Server Cluster with Data Not Expiring

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I started a 3-node Ignite cluster without enabling persistence. After running for a period of time, I found that the cached data on one node will never expire, while the other two nodes can expire normally.

I connect and insert data using the following method:

```
public class InsertData05 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();
        clientConfiguration.setAddresses("127.0.0.1:10800");
        IgniteClient client = Ignition.startClient(clientConfiguration);

        ClientCacheConfiguration configuration = new ClientCacheConfiguration();
        configuration.setName("test");
        configuration.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REPLICATED);

        ClientCache<Object, Object> cache = client.getOrCreateCache(configuration);
        Duration duration = new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS, 60);
        ExpiryPolicy expiryPolicy = ModifiedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(duration).create();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            cache.withExpiryPolicy(expiryPolicy).put("bb" + i,"bb");
        }

        client.close();
    }
}
```

After opening the DEBUG log of the Ignite server node, it was found that the problematic node no longer appears to scan for expired data on the off heap cache and place it in the queue. In its log, there is only information similar to the following:

```
[2023-08-31 17:51:01.355][DEBUG][GridTimeoutProcessor] Timeout has occurred [obj=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.topology.PartitionsEvictManager$1$1@qso42s7c, process=true]
[2023-08-31 17:51:01.355][DEBUG][GridClosureProcessor] Grid runnable started: closure-proc-worker
[2023-08-31 17:51:01.355][DEBUG][PartitionsEvictManager] After filling the evict queue [res=0, tombstone=true, size=0]
[2023-08-31 17:51:01.355][DEBUG][GridClosureProcessor] Grid runnable finished normally: closure-proc-worker
```

In the normal node log, there will be the following logs:

```
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.265][DEBUG][GridTimeoutProcessor] Timeout has occurred [obj=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.topology.PartitionsEvictManager$1$1@670cf995, process=true]
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.265][DEBUG][GridTimeoutProcessor] Timeout has occurred [obj=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.topology.PartitionsEvictManager$1$1@7f8e158b, process=true]
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.265][DEBUG][GridClosureProcessor] Grid runnable started: closure-proc-worker
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.265][DEBUG][GridClosureProcessor] Grid runnable started: closure-proc-worker
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.265][DEBUG][PartitionsEvictManager] After filling the evict queue [res=0, tombstone=false, size=0]
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.266][DEBUG][PartitionsEvictManager] After filling the evict queue [res=0, tombstone=true, size=0]
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.266][DEBUG][GridClosureProcessor] Grid runnable finished normally: closure-proc-worker
[2023-08-31 17:51:00.266][DEBUG][GridClosureProcessor] Grid runnable finished normally: closure-proc-worker
```

Version:

I am using Gridgain Community Edition version 8.8.9

What are the possible reasons for non tombstone data not being scanned? I found GG-34133, which seems to have been optimized here, but I am unable to view its detailed information. Is there a correlation between the two?

Answer (score 0):

This does look like a bug. Since you're using a pretty old version (nearly two years old at this point), I would suggest upgrading. The ticket you reference -- fixed in 8.8.11 -- might be relevant, but I can't be completely sure.

Comment: We are using version 8.8.9 stably in the production environment, so it may be difficult to directly introduce version 8.8.11. Therefore, I would like to take a look at the specific information described in the fixed GG-34133 in 8.8.11. However, it seems that I do not have access permissions. If it is convenient, could you please paste information about this ticket on stackhoverflow?      https://ggsystems.atlassian.net/browse/GG-34133

Comment: I can't share details from our internal bug tracker. I would suggest upgrading to the newest version (currently 8.8.33) rather than a different release with a 2022 vintage.